# Sidebar bootstrap : 3 clicks necessary to open it on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I have a problem on my mobile when I want to open my sidebar by clicking on the sidebar-toggle: the menu only opens after an average of 3 clicks, the first two don't work.

Any ideas ?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: please post your code here. It will help everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you are clicking for the first time you are not removing the `sidebar-collapse` class and add `sidebar-open` class. Instead You are adding `sidebar-open` without removing `sidebar-collapse`.